# Having trouble working with Dynamic Arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-arrays

I'm doing this project for my programming class and I'm having a hard time understanding how I'm supposed to be using dynamic arrays with classes. The idea is that I'm supposed to allow the user to enter how many payrolls records they want to create. When I run the program everything seems to go smoothly until I tell the program there are no more employees I want to enter for that one payroll, at that point normally the program will close itself. Instead it crashes and creates a break point looking at the delete [] payroll; line in main. Because it's pointing at that line I'm assuming I'm creating dynamic arrays incorrectly but I'm not really sure what I'm supposed to change and where. Appreciate any help or tips I can get on this.

This is my Header file for my Payroll class

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Payroll
{
    private:
    int empNum;
    static int total_payrolls;
    double pay;
    double hours;
    string firstname;
    string lastname;

public:

    Payroll();

    Payroll(int en, double p, double h, string fn, string ln);

    ~Payroll();

    int getEmpNum();
    double getPay();
    double getHours();
    string getFirstname();
    string getLastname();
    double getTotalPay();

    void setEmpNum(int);
    void setPay(double);
    void setHours(double);
    void setFirstname(string);
    void setLastname(string);

};
#endif
```

This is my Payroll class file

```
#include "Header.h"
using namespace std;

Payroll::Payroll()
{
    int empNum = 0;
    int total_payrolls = 0;
    total_payrolls++;
    double pay = 0.0;
    double hours = 0.0;
}

Payroll::Payroll(int en, double p, double h, string fn, string ln)
{
    empNum = en;
    pay = p;
    hours = h;
    firstname = fn;
    lastname = ln;
}

Payroll::~Payroll()
{

}

int Payroll::getEmpNum()
{
    return empNum;
}

double Payroll::getPay()
{
    return pay;
}

double Payroll::getHours()
{
    return hours;
}
string Payroll::getFirstname()
{
    return firstname;
}

string Payroll::getLastname()
{
    return lastname;
}

void Payroll::setEmpNum(int en)
{
    empNum = en;
}

void Payroll::setPay(double p)
{
    pay = p;
}
void Payroll::setHours(double h)
{
    hours = h;
}

void Payroll::setFirstname(string fn)
{
    firstname = fn;
}

void Payroll::setLastname(string ln)
{
    lastname = ln;
}

double Payroll::getTotalPay()
{
    return (pay * hours);
}
```

Here's my main

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "Header.h"
using namespace std;


int main()
{

    string first_name;
    string last_name;
    int employee_number;
    int choice1;
    int choice2;
    int capacity;
    int num_of_employees;
    double pay_rate;
    double hours_worked;
    char doAgain;
    ofstream outputFile;
    outputFile.open("cop2224_proj2.txt ");


    Payroll *payroll;


    cout << "How many payrolls would you like to enter? ";
    cin >> capacity;
    payroll = new Payroll [capacity];

    cout << "Welcome to the employee payroll program \n";
    cout << "The purpose of this program is to collect employee \n";
    cout << "Payroll information, calculate that information \n";
    cout << "and store the information on a file \n";
    cout << "Please select an option below \n";
    cout << endl;
    cout << "1. Enter employee payrate information \n";
    cout << "2. Quit program \n";
    cout << "Enter your choice \n";
    cin >> choice1;


    do
    {

        while ((choice1 < 1) || (choice1 > 2))
        {
            cout << "Invaild input, only enter 1 or 2 into the keyboard \n";
            cin >> choice1;
        }

        if (choice1 != 2)
        {
            cout << "You have selected to enter the program \n";


            cout << "----------------------------------------- \n";


            cout << "Enter your 6 digit employee number \n";
            cin >> employee_number;
            while ((employee_number < 99999) || (employee_number > 1000000))
            {
                cout << "Only enter a number consisting of 6 digits \n ";
                cin >> employee_number;
            }

            cout << "Enter your first name \n";
            cin >> first_name;
            cout << "Enter your last name \n";
            cin >> last_name;
            cout << "Enter your payrate \n";
            cin >> pay_rate;

            cout << "Enter the amount of hours worked \n";
            cin >> hours_worked;

            payroll[capacity].setHours(hours_worked);
            payroll[capacity].setFirstname(first_name);
            payroll[capacity].setLastname(last_name);
            payroll[capacity].setHours(hours_worked);
            payroll[capacity].setPay(pay_rate);


            cout << payroll[capacity].getEmpNum() << ',' << endl;
            cout << payroll[capacity].getFirstname() << ',' << endl;
            cout << payroll[capacity].getLastname() << ',' << endl;
            cout << payroll[capacity].getPay() << ',' << endl;
            cout << payroll[capacity].getHours() << ',' << endl;
            cout << payroll[capacity].getTotalPay() << ',' << endl;

            cout << "Do you want to imput another employee's information? (Y/N)";
            cin >> doAgain;
        }


    } while (doAgain == 'Y' || doAgain == 'y');


    delete [] payroll;
    payroll = 0;
    outputFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: (1) Array indexes start from 0, so allocating an array of size `capacity` and using `payroll[capacity]` is indexing off the end of the array. (2) Using `capacity` each time round the loop is probably not what you intended, each  payroll class should be using it's own array element. Starting from 0 up to but not including `capacity`.